# How to verify if a cloud storage provider is really "zero-knowledge"?

Tags: security, encryption, cloud

Note: For a specific example, I'm going to be using [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/), but I'm interested in applying this question more broadly to any "private" storage or messaging service.

SpiderOak claims to be a "zero-knowledge" cloud storage platform, meaning that any data you store is encrypted on your computer before it is uploaded, using encryption keys that SpiderOak does not have access to.  However, to use the service, you must download and install SpiderOak's application binaries (no source code provided), and give that application access to your encryption key so that it can perform the encryption.

Without reviewing the source code, is it possible to verify that the application does not do something fishy?  By "something fishy" I mean things like: uploading the user's key to their servers, 
collecting personal information or metadata from the user's computer, etc...  How can the application authors prove that their app does not do these things?

**Update:** I guess short of having the source code or decompiling (which is really the same thing, just a really roundabout way of getting it) there's no way to guarantee an app is safe

Comment: You can certainly try to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: You might get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a proxy, like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), or a lower level network analysis tool, like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), to watch your network traffic while you are using the application. This would allow you to see if there is any traffic beyond what you intend (i.e. grabbing metadata) or containing data you don't want to send (i.e. your keys).

If you don't see any traffic that makes you suspicious, but you still don't trust the application, you could try running the binaries through a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), and then go digging through the source that generates. Be aware, decompilers are far from perfect, and their output can be obtuse (at best), so this will be a very labor intensive endeavor.

Comment: Wireshark / Fiddler would be a way to prove that the app DOES do something wrong, but it wouldn't prove the opposite.
Also, if the application were to encrypt what it collected before uploading it, it would be very difficult to determine if the payload were legit or not.